# Proper way to move a pool with virsh to another partition?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vagrant, linux-kvm, virsh

The root partition is running out of space so i'd like to move the machines to another directory. They are currently on `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`, the pool is called **images**. The VMs are spun up with Vagrant and im using KVM/libvirt as the provider.

So far what i've tried is:

1. Shut down the VM with Vagrant
2. Create a new directory under `/home/images/`
3. chown qemu:qemu `/home/images`
4. move the images from `/var/lib/libvirt/images` to `/home/images`
5. Create new pool and point it at `/home/images`
6. edit each VM with `virsh edit` and change the path of the disk.
7. start the VM

Any easier/better way to do this?

Comment: this does not refresh the volume list......

Comment: edit: seems like if you do not undefine/define the VM, vagrant can work with it but in virsh vol-list it does not show, no idea how to do this.